# XSL - List equivalent implementation

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I would like to know if we have something in XSL 2.0, equivalent to a List in Java. I would like to recursively call a template 10 times and pass a input variable with name 'mylist'. Within the template, I want to do operations like adding item to list, removing item from list, iterating over items within the list etc. I could see something like 'sequence' but i am not sure if it can be used to add, remove, iterate etc. Please share your ideas to implement this.

I tried using sequence with the help of the below reponse, I face some issues with syntax, like declaring an empty sequence. I want to print the sequence 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10, using the insert-before or concat sequnce functions. Please help me fix the syntax.

```
  <xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
  xmlns:locator="http://ntr.lxnx.org"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
  <xsl:template match="/"> 
  <xsl:variable name="output">
  <xsl:call-template name="calculate-data"> 
                <xsl:with-param 
                    name="sequence" 
                    select=""/> 
                 <xsl:with-param 
                    name="count"  
                    select="1"/>
            </xsl:call-template> 
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:value-of select="output"></xsl:value-of>
  </xsl:template>  
  <xsl:variable name="main-root" as="document-node()" select="/"/>

  <xsl:template name="calculate-data">
<xsl:param name="sequence"/>
  <xsl:param name="count" select="0"/>
<xsl:if test="$count != 10">
                fn:insert-before($count as item()*,0 as xs:integer,$sequence as item()*)
                <xsl:call-template name="calculate-data"> 
                    <xsl:with-param 
                        name="sequence" 
                        select="$sequence"/> 
                     <xsl:with-param 
                        name="count"  
                        select="$count + 1"/>
                </xsl:call-template>              


</xsl:if> 
        </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You can iterate on sequences. You will be able to apply templates to sequences in XSLT 3.0.- About adding/removing: do notice that XSLT is a declarative language, those functions will produce a new instance.

Comment: Rachel, perhaps you could provide a small example of the sort of input/output you want? The reason I ask is that XSL is not normally used as a procedural language, so changing values in a list as you iterate over it isn't normally the ideal way to solve a problem. Rather, you would specify what it is you want your end result to be, not how to get to that result.

Comment: @Erica: Your point is very true. I am interested in using sequence to achieve the solution because I want to learn more. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**With the clarification that an instance of a sequence, as anything else in XPath/XSLT are immutable, the answer is positive**:

1. **Iterating over a sequence**:

   ```
   <xsl:for-each select="$seq">
    <!-- Whatever necessary code here -->
    <!-- . is the current item of the sequence-->
   </xsl:for-each>
   ```
2. [**Add an item to a sequence**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-insert-before) (produces a new sequence that is the result of this operation):

   ```
      insert-before($target as item()*,
                    $position as xs:integer,
                    $inserts as item()*) as item()*
   ```

> **Summary**: Returns a new sequence constructed from the value of $target
>   with the value of $inserts inserted at
>   the position specified by the value of
>   $position. (The value of $target is
>   not affected by the sequence
>   construction.)

`.`3. [**Concatenation of two sequences**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-concatenate) (produces a new sequence that is the result of this operation):

```
   $seq1 , $seq2
```

`.`.4. [**Remove an item from a sequence**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-remove):

```
     remove($target as item()*, $position as xs:integer) as item()*
```

> **Summary**: Returns a new sequence constructed from the value of $target
>   with the item at the position
>   specified by the value of $position
>   removed

`.`.5. [**Extract a subsequence from a sequence**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-subsequence):

> ```
>    subsequence($sourceSeq as item()*,
>                $startingLoc as xs:double,
>                $length as xs:double) **as item**()*
> ```
>
> **Summary**: Returns the contiguous sequence of items in the value of
>   $sourceSeq beginning at the position
>   indicated by the value of $startingLoc
>   and continuing for the number of items
>   indicated by the value of $length.

And there are many more useful **[standard XPath 2.0 functions over sequences](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#sequence-functions)**.

**Note**: The only feature that the XPath 2.0 sequence doesn't have is "nestedness". A sequence is always "flat" and an item of a sequence cannot be a sequence itself. There are ways to simulate multi-level sequences -- for example, an item can be a node and its children nodes can be regarded as a nested sequence.

**Update**: Here is how these functions can be used conveniently to solve the OP's updated question:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 xmlns:my="my:my" >

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:sequence select="my:populateSequence((), 1, 10)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:function name="my:populateSequence" as="xs:integer*">
  <xsl:param name="pSeq" as="xs:integer*"/>
  <xsl:param name="pStart" as="xs:integer"/>
  <xsl:param name="pEnd" as="xs:integer"/>

  <xsl:sequence select=
   "if($pStart gt $pEnd)
      then $pSeq
      else my:populateSequence(($pSeq, $pStart), $pStart+1, $pEnd)
   "/>
 </xsl:function>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this XSLT 2.0 transformation is applied on any XML document (not used), the wanted result is produced**:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: I appreciate your ideas sharing. I face syntax issues implementing this. I have updated my post with the xsl. Please provide you comments to declare empty sequence and insertion of items into the sequence. Thanks.

Comment: @Rachel: With pleasure -- I am travelling back home from work and will update my answer when I am at home. What you are asking for can be done very easily and with elegance :)

Comment: @Rachel: I have updated my answer with the solution to your new problem. Please, ask new questions as ... new questions.

Comment: @Rachel: As you see, for this simple problem you even don't need `insert-before()` -- using just the concatenation operator `,` solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks Dimitri. I will certainly take your comment. This solution is perfect. I am quite familiar with using recursive functions but not with usage of sequence. I am trying to figure out how the same can be implemented using a sequence. Please share your ideas about using sequence to achive this. It wil be of great help to me.

Comment: @Rachel: What do you mean by "how the same can be implemented using a sequence." ? My solution *is* using a sequence.

Comment: Yes Dimitri. You are right that the above solution also uses sequence & is the best way to achieve. In the above post, you have shared functions like insert-before/concat etc. In the example, instead of having the items within the sequence as integer, i want to have them as string and construct sequence using the predefined functions that you had suggested before. I want know how to start with passing an empty sequence as a param to a template and then recursively call the template to create the complete sequence of items. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: @Rachel, for this simple problem you really don't need `insert-before()`. This function is most necessary when an item should be inserted not at the ends of a sequence, but at some mid-position. You need to come up with a more challenging problem (as I said -- submit it as a new question), that really warrants the use of other sequence functions. :)

Comment: How about using concat to append to the end. After reading your reply on sequence functions I am very curious about knowing answers for the below 2 queries. 1) Usage of a sample sequence function 2) Passing an empty sequence as a param to a template call. I wil be very happy to see them.

Comment: @Rachel: `$seq, $item` produces a new sequence, that is the result of appending the item `$item` to the end of the sequence `$seq`. And the expression `$seq1, $seq2` produces a new sequence that is the result of concatenating these two sequences. You really don't need anything else to express these operations. :)

Comment: @as for passing an empty sequence to a function, you already have an example for this in my solution -- read well.

Comment: Thanks Dimitri. I appreciate your quick responses.

Comment: +1 This is a good answer, indeed. Just because someone might think not in the general problem but in this particularly, `1 to 10` will produce this sequence `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`