# passing the line break HTML element to XSL

Tags: java, html, xslt-2.0

I have a method methodA() which returns an arraylist of elements.Now I am trying to prepare HTML report using XSL.

Here is what I am doing:

First I am preparing an XML for my XSL file.Say I am creating a textnode as:

```
Element unusedX = docforXSL.createElement("Unused");
unusedX.appendChild(docforXSL.createTextNode(StringUtils.join(methodA().iterator(), ",")));
```

My XML will look like

```
<Unused>arraylist elements separated by commas</Unused>
```

Here I am using the join() method of Commons.lang StringUtils which takes second parameter as separator.Right now I am using comma(,) as a separator.My XSL code which will render this node is:

```
<td align = "center"><xsl:value-of select="Unused"/></td>
```

Here I will get my arraylist elements separated by commas in a column of my report.

In my HTML report I want each arraylist element to be on different line(line break) instead of being separated by commas.

If I am giving HTML line break(br) or \n as second parameter it is not rendering them properly in HTML file.

Kindly advice!!!

Answer (score 0):

.createTextNode treats the text as plain text, not HTML.

Please see [Javascript, trying to add linebreak inside create text node method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13041388/javascript-trying-to-add-linebreak-inside-create-text-node-method)

Comment: Hi Ross I am doing all this on the fly using Java and XSL. I am not sure but I doubt whether it would work the same here as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XSL to first [tokenize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487704/how-to-make-xsl-tokenize-work) the value of `Unused` and later [iterate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810019/xsl-list-equivalent-implementation) over the sequence created by tokenization and add the line breaks.
The answers to [XSL: Construct an Array from a Delimited String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314688/xsl-construct-an-array-from-a-delimited-string) contains some nice examples showing how to do this kind of transformation.

Comment: I am doing all this on the fly using Java and XSL. Is it possible to add some function in my XSL file so that it interprets the text(separator) that I am passing from Java file as the line break and can do the trick for me?

Comment: Do you have a special reason why the separator should be treated as the line break? if you can achieve this with XSL by splitting the String and iterating over the values, does it make a difference to you?

Comment: No,I was just thinking if it can be done that way.But now I changed the Java code which is creating number of textnodes equal to the number of elements in the arraylist. Thus I am easily able to give line break between the elements now using XSL.